# Any idioms to express calling or visiting a company to get information, pretending to be customer?

Tags: single-word-requests

What expression can you use to describe someone who  visits a company pretending to be  their customer, only to get  some information.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the term for this?"

Comment: Are you asking about corporate espionage, or something as innocent as evaluating a product in a brick-and-mortar store knowing that you will ultimately be ordering online?

Answer (score 3):

***[Fishing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fishing)*** is a term with a meaning close to what you are referring to:.

> - A search or investigation undertaken with the hope, though not the stated purpose, of discovering information.

ODO

Comment: Ah! I thought the OP meant "How do I write..." My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked several jobs in retail, finance, food service, and IT, we've always called a person that does this a "secret shopper" if they work for the company, or if they were sent in by someone who works for the company. The purpose is generally to evaluate employees on their procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Undercover, perhaps?

> undercover
>
> `/ʌndəˈkʌvə,ˈʌndə-/`
>
> adjective
>
> involving secret work within a community or organization, especially for the purposes of police investigation or espionage.
>
> "an undercover police operation"
>
> synonyms:  covert, secret, clandestine, private, confidential, conspiratorial, underground, surreptitious, furtive, cloak-and-dagger, hole-and-corner, hugger-mugger, back-alley, backstair, stealthy, closet; intelligence; hidden, concealed, masked, veiled, shrouded; black; informalhush-hush, sneaky
>
> "they were arrested after a three-year undercover investigation"